# how can I pass the parameter with a html button having php href

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and want my button to pass the `state_id` to a `download` function in my `Newhome` Controller.

My code goes like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Newhome/download')?>/state_id" onclick="" class="btn btn-primary" type="" >Download</a>
```

But I am unable to pass this variable.
Please suggest the way out.

Thank you for any contribution in advance.

---

The solution goes like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Newhome/download/'.$state_id)?>" onclick="" class="btn btn-primary" type="" >Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Newhome/download/'.$state_id)?>" onclick="" class="btn btn-primary" type="" >Download</a>
```

or

```
<?php echo anchor(base_url('index.php/Newhome/download/'.$state_id), 'Download', $attributes = array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
Note : "You need to load form helpers"
```